# Spring security working tomcat server(Eclipse) but when i put war file tomcat webapp then spring security not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

> I'm not really a Java developer,I'm using SpringBoot and everything
>   works fine when the application runs in Tomcat on my local
>   machine(Eclipse) and on our testing server. However, as soon as the
>   application war file put in  Tomcat webapp folder it's as if there is
>   no security at all with all routes accessible. Login and logout routes
>   are non-existent as well.
>
> That being said. Everything else appears to work fine, just without
>   any security at all.
>   PhishcopDashBoardApplication.java

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;


@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebSecurity
public class PhishcopDashBoardApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer    {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PhishcopDashBoardApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

> WebSecurityConfig.java

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter  {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(WebSecurityConfig.class);

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        logger.info("configure");
          //   System.out.println("hi  ashwani");
        //

         http .authorizeRequests() .antMatchers("/assets/**","/partial/**",
          "/register").permitAll() .anyRequest().authenticated() .and()
         .formLogin() .loginPage("/login").usernameParameter("email").permitAll().and().logout().permitAll();
         logger.info("complete");
         }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }
}
```

> pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.kratikal.phishcop</groupId>
    <artifactId>Dashboard</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    <name>Dashboard</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mashape.unirest</groupId>
            <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Tomcat embedded container -->
    <!--    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency> -->
        <!-- Need this to compile JSP, tomcat-embed-jasper version is not working, 
            no idea why -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
            <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Optional, test for static content, bootstrap CSS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

> Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any useful log in tomcat log folder?

Comment: @asyard there is no useful log in tomcat log folder